# The array is updated within the loop but outside the loop is empty

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I tried to define array in the next way:

```
#!/bin/bash

function try {
local arr=()
    sort -n a.txt | while read line; do
        arr=("${arr[@]}" "${line}")
        declare -p arr
    done
declare -p arr
}

try
```

and I get a strange thing - during the `while` the array updating and everything is ok. but outside the while loop i get that arr is empty.

What is going on here?

---

Edit: after the first answer, what with this way (without pipeline like his suggestion):

```
#!/bin/bash

function try {
local arr=()
    while read line; do
        arr+=("${line}")
        declare -p arr
    done < "`sort -n a.txt`"
declare -p arr
}

try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this (requires bash):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# declare an array
arr=()

# loop through results of sort and populate an array
while read -r line; do
   arr+=( "$line" )
done < <(sort -n a.txt)

# Check array content
declare -p arr
```

- Don't use pipeline to avoid forking a subshell, use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) instead. Changes made in subshell are not seen in parent shell.
- Use `array+=(item)` syntax to append an item to array

---

Note that using `bash` you can also use `mapfile` and avoid `while` loop:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(sort -n a.txt)
```

Comment: Ok. I edited my question in according to your answer. Can you take a look? (where is the problem in this way?)

Comment: Backticks is used for command substitution not process substitution. I've included a link in my answer on process substitution. Please read it.

Comment: Ok. thank you about a full answer. By the way, you meet a way to do it with pipeline? (Just from a curiosity. I want to explore the language)

Comment: Ok, and with `<` operator it's not possible too?

Comment: Pipe can be used inside process substitution command e.g.  `while read -r line; do
   arr+=( "$line" )
done < <(sort -n a.txt | grep 'abc')` but pipe cannot be used in front of `while` loop.

Comment: Yes I understood it - I meant to case the pipe used in front of `while` loop (thank you for your clear answer). But anyway, with `<` operator it's not possible too?

Comment: I don't speak about pipeline. I ask just about `<` operator (even without pipeline) - It's not possible?

Comment: you did it with `< <`

Comment: That means you still haven't read the article I included in my answer. `<(...)` is process substitution syntax and `<` before that is used for input redirection.